# Any security risks with sudo password from standard input over ssh?

Tags: shell, security, ssh, sudo

I want to execute sudo over ssh on remote servers and supply the password over standard input. The following code is in a shell script on a secured server with restricted access. The password is asked beforehand and the servers use all the same sudo password. The someaction can surely take some seconds to execute.

Here is the shell script extract:

```
read -s -p "please enter your sudo password" PASSWORD
ssh user@host1 -t "echo '$PASSWORD' | sudo -S someaction"
ssh user@host2 -t "echo '$PASSWORD' | sudo -S someaction"
```

My question: Is it safe to use echo with a pipe? And are here any security problems that might occur, like logging the echo result on the remote server, etc?

Maybe somebody has a better suggestion?

Note: I know other tools can do this, like ansible etc. I am not looking for another similar tool, just want to know whether using ssh/echo/sudo in the mentioned way is safe.

Comment: Maybe not on the server, but certainly on the node where you execute these commands. `$PASSWORD` is visible as it is an environment variable.

Comment: good point, but the code is inside a script, and the assumption is that the script is not manipulated or tweaked by others. I will adjust the question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes!**

As long as the command is running anybody that can view all processes can view that password, by running `ps aux | grep echo`:

```
root     [..] zsh -c echo topsecret | sudo -C action
```

You could configure `sudo` to not ask the password for a specific task for a user, that would certainly increase security over this solution.

Comment: In the OPs case the actions can vary a lot, so configuring sudoers is not an option. Thanks for the note on ps aux

Comment: I haven’t been able to reproduce this on OS X. It indeed shows the `sudo` command, but not the `echo` that pipes to it. What OS are you using? And in it, what about if you read `stdin` another way, i.e. `sudo -S someaction <<< "$PASSWORD"`, does your method still work to uncover the password?